# Another Learning Java conundrum

Tags: java

Once again I come to the experts for assistance. 
In my last post I mentioned me being still in school, This time we are going through a chapter on interfaces (book shows no code no examples). The assignment this time is as follows "Create an interface called Tuner with a method tune. Create two classes called radio and guitar that implement this interface. In main, create instances of each of these classes, and invoke the tune method for each instance." I feel like I am completely of the rails on this one. As before I do not need the solution just someone to put it in DUMDUM terms again.

This is what I have so far.

```
public interface Tuner {
public abstract void tune();
}


public class Guitar extends Tuner implements Tune{

 public static void main()  {
public void tune(){

 }}}




public class Radio extends Tuner implements tune{

public static void main(){


}}
```

I appreciate any advice on the matter!!!!

These are my latest changes:

```
package interfaces;
interface Tuner {
   public abstract void tune();
 }



package interfaces;
class Radio implements Tuner {
 public void tune(){
 }

 }

package interfaces;
class Guitar implements Tuner {
 public void tune(){
 }
  }
```

Please feel free to tell me I am still barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Dude, you've got to read about OOD: at leat get some idea about (in no particular order) abstraction, polymorphism, inheritance, and object life-cycle.

Comment: one way to look at it,is if you implement an interface you MUST use all the methods. So Guitar and Radio must use ALL of the methods in the Tuner interface if they implement it. If you extend a Tuner CLASS, all of the methods in the Tuner class are available to you, but you do not have to use them all if you don't need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues I see in what you have so far:

- In Java, an `interface`'s methods are all `public abstract` so they don't need to be declared as such.
- A Java `class` can extend another `class` or `abstract class` but implements an `interface`. So in your case, your Guitar should implement the Tuner class, and would contain an implementation of the methods that are declared in the interface that it implements, in this case, the `tune` method.
- The `main` method is the entry point into the application, and your application should only need one of these.  Then, within that method you would create an instance of a `Guitar` and an instance of a `Radio` and call the `tune` method on each of those instantiated objects.

Comment: On point 1: In Java, an interface contains *only* public abstract methods and public static final variables. Both public and abstract are implied and denoting the methods as such are left to the programmer's discretion. (more typing == no one ever does)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I am attempting a few immediate changes right now!

Comment: True story @RayStojonic.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As another question? If only one main method is needed would it go in one of the classes that implement tuner or would it be put in the tuner interface? My apologies if the question makes little sense.

Comment: The main class cannot go into the interface. That makes no sense and the program would not compile anyway

Comment: The main method must exist in a class, not an interface.  I probably wouldn't put it in any of those classes, but would have some other class as the main application class.  Seems like most instructors would tell you to name it Ch27Prob10 or Application or MyAppClass or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

This should get you moving in the right direction: In Java, we `extend` classes and `implement` interfaces.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the advice and the response!

Answer (score 0):

1. `interface`s do not have `abstract` methods - all methods are abstract by definition.
2. All members of an `interface` are `public` by default - you do not need the `public`.
3. You implement an `interface` and extend a `class`. You need to `implements Tuner`.
4. The `implements Tune` is just superfluous.